# How can I update 3 tables at the same time with 4 id fields?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, sql-update

I have a form for adding offers that belong to companies. I can delete and add them but I can't get the edit to use.

When I click edit only 1 table changes and I don't know how to work this out. I am using codeigniter.

My table structure:

```
Aanbiedingen
idaanbiedingen | Aanbieding | Omschrijving | prijs | conditie

fotoaanbiedingen
idfotoaanbiedingen | fotonaam

bedrijfaanbiedingen
idbedrijfaanbiedingen | idaanbiedingen | idfotoaanbiedingen | idbedrijven
```

my bedrijven table is just the company. I use the id to link them to the offer.

My controller looks like this:

```
function editaanbieding()
{
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data = array(
        'Aanbieding' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingnaam'),
        'Tekst' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingomschrijving'),
        'Prijs' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingprijs'),
        'Conditie' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingconditie')
    );
    $this->aanbieding_model->edit_aanbieding($data, $id);
    redirect('members/aanbiedingen');
}
```

My model looks like:

```
function get_aanbiedingen()
{
    $id = $this->uri->segment(2);
    $this->db->where('bedrijfaanbiedingen.idbedrijven', $id);
    $this->db->join('fotoaanbiedingen', 'bedrijfaanbiedingen.idfotoaanbiedingen = fotoaanbiedingen.idfotoaanbiedingen');
    $this->db->join('bedrijven', 'bedrijfaanbiedingen.idbedrijven = bedrijven.idbedrijven');
    $this->db->join('Aanbiedingen', 'bedrijfaanbiedingen.idaanbiedingen = Aanbiedingen.idaanbiedingen');

    $query = $this->db->get('bedrijfaanbiedingen');
    return $query->result_array();
}

function edit_aanbieding($data, $id)
{
    $this->db->where('idaanbiedingen', $id);
    $this->db->update('Aanbiedingen', $data); 

    $this->insert_bedrijfcat1($id); 
}

function insert_bedrijfcat1($id) 
{     
    $id2 = $this->session->userdata('idbedrijven');
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($id2);
    die;
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `bedrijfaanbiedingen` WHERE `idaanbiedingen` = '" . $id. "'");

    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `bedrijfaanbiedingen` (`idaanbiedingen`, `idbedrijven`, `idfotoaanbiedingen` ) VALUES ('".$id."', '".$id2."', '".$id3."')");
}
```

But I am missing a lot of code. I'm struggling with this all day. So I don't see an solution for this.

My edit form looks like this:

```
<div id="cpanel">
<?php foreach($aanb as $aanb) ?>
<h2>Aanbieding: <?php echo $aanb['Aanbieding']; ?> voor: <?php echo $aanb['Bedrijfsnaam'];?>, aanpassen</h2>
<br/>
<b>Pas hier uw aanbieding toe.</b>
<?php echo br(2); ?>
<?= validation_errors(); ?>
<?php $id = $this->uri->segment(3); ?>
<?= form_open_multipart("members/editaanbieding/$id");?>

<?php $options = array(
    'Nieuw' => 'Nieuw',
    'Gebruikt' => 'Gebruikt'
    );
?>

<table>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Aanbieding:');?></td>
    <td><?= form_input('aanbiedingnaam', $aanb['Aanbieding']);?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Omschrijving:');?></td>
    <td><?= form_textarea('aanbiedingomschrijving', $aanb['Tekst']);?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Prijs:');?></td>
    <td>€ <input type="number" name='aanbiedingprijs' step="any" value="<?php echo $aanb['Prijs']?>" /><td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Conditie:');?></td>
    <td><?= form_dropdown('aanbiedingconditie', $options);?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Foto');?></td>
    <td><?= form_upload('aanbiedingfoto');?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_submit('submit', 'Verzenden');?></td>
    <td><?= form_reset('reset', 'Reset'); ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>members/aanbiedingen">Terug</a>
<?php form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

Hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You mean update query?

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name
WHERE ;
```

Comment: Please read my question. I am updating but it does not work. I can't update my three tables.

Comment: Insert and Delete work. But you use update in a different way. Try it like Insert and Delete? use multiple querys at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$this->db->where('a_id',$a_id);
$this->db->where('b_id',$b_id);
$this->db->where('c_id',$c_id);
$this->db->where('d_id',$d_id);
$this->db->update('yourtable',$data_posted);
```

Comment: I don't have all the id's. I only have the Aanbiedingen.idaanbiedingen bedrijfaanbiedingen.idaanbiedingen and bedrijven.idbedrijven

Comment: I just need to update the 3 tables I mentioned above. But I don´t know how to do that.

Comment: ok than update one table and pass its id to another table and update them.

Comment: I don't know how to build the query. that's why i'm asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do as I was unable to understand the question, what do you want to update on each table but have you considered using MySQL triggers?

Comment: This could be in a comment. but I considered that. but I don't know how to build te query. that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: you are right - this could have been in a comment but i am not able to add a comment, i love the MySql Triggers & Foreign key which gives much power to the Database itself and takes some load from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest, solution i can think of, use `transactions`, the advantage of transactions in codeigniter, is that if one of the query fails, it will rollback.

```
function update($table1data,$table2data,$table3data,$table1id,$table2id,$table3id)
{
   $this->db->trans_start(); //start transaction
   $this->db->set($table1data)->where('id',$table1id)->update('table1');
   $this->db->set($table2data)->where('id',$table2id)->update('table2');
   $this->db->set($table3data)->where('id',$table3id)->update('table3');
   $this->db->trans_complete(); // end transaction
}
```

you could also use `active record` inside the transaction block, in you're problem all you need to do is to pass the **idfotoaanbiedingen** and **idaanbiedingen** inside the *method*, and from there do the update you want.

Read More at.
[transaction - codeigniter userguide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html)

Comment: I need to know how to make the query. not the call to the query. could you edit?

Comment: @KeesSonnema, basically just pass the id and data you need to update. Just a simple Update will do. And on you're update form, just query the  **idfotoaanbiedingen** and **idaanbiedingen** and send it to the view as hidden field.

Comment: Yes I'm a bit stuck at getting all the id values. I could only get 2 of them I guess. but will look at this tommorrow :)

Comment: I already fixed it using form_hidden inputs. Thanks anyway :)